# Convertir de NVARCHAR A FLOAT

Tags: sql

Buen dia colegas quisiera saber si existe alguna forma  en sql de convertir  de nvarchar a datetime

el  caso es que tengo una columna llamada fecha pero sus valores estan en nvarchar

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y quisiera que se me mostrara como datetime , e intentado de todo desde cast hasta convert y solo me marca error , si existiera alguna forma en verdad se los agradeceria ,saludos

Comment: ¿Cual manejador de base de datos estás utilizando? Cada uno tiene una sintaxis distinta. Si solo muestra el mes y año ¿Se asume el primer día del mes?

Comment: Tu problema en definitiva se trata de convertir una cadena con cierto formato a un datetime. Es posible solucionarlo, pero es fundamental conocer que posibles formatos te puedes encontrar en esta columna, ¿Todas las posibilidades se reducen a mes(3)-año(2)? ¿cuál es el menor año posible y cuál el máximo? ¿si tienes 18 podemos estar seguros que es 2018 y no 1918?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho el numero en este caso es  18 significa el numero de año osea' 2018'  ejemplo Enero2018(ene-18) ,Febrero 2019(feb-19)

Comment: @LuisCazares Es SQL server  el managment studio

Comment: Si el formato es siempre el mismo, 1) Crea una tabla de reemplazo con las 12 cadenas de meses y el número de mes que le corresponde 2) divide el campo en dos partes  para mes y año 3) Al año le concatenas `20` salvo los casos que sean años del siglo pasado que deberías concatenar `19` 3) Con la parte del mes haces un `join` con la tabla de reemplazo y concatenas el número de mes, 4) Agregas un `01` para indicar el día 5) Deberías finalizar con una cadena formato `yyyy-mm-dd`, esto se convierte a `datetime` con un simple `convert`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para poder convertir esa cadena en una fecha (tipo de dato: `Date`), la cadena tiene que tener una fecha válida, tendrías que concatenarle el día al principio. Ej: '01-ene-18'.

Asegurate de haber especificado como lenguaje español para la sesión, porque el mes está en español:

```
SET LANGUAGE Spanish;
```

Para convertir la cadena a tipo `Date` puedes usar la función `CONVERT()`:

```
SELECT CONVERT(date, '01-ene-40') AS fecha
```

Si quisieras convertirla a `datetime` especifica `datetime` en lugar de `date` en la query, aunque no tiene mucho sentido porque no tienes información de la hora, minutos y segundos (van a salir todos en cero).

Si quieres convertir toda la columna `fecha` (nvarchar) de la tabla `t`, la query sería:

```
SELECT CONVERT(date, '01-' + fecha) AS fecha
FROM t;
```

Ten en cuenta que está query no actualiza la tabla, si quisieras guardar la fecha con formato `date` deberías agregar una nueva columna de tipo `date` en la tabla y hacer un `UPDATE`.

Como el año tiene 2 dígitos, ten en cuenta:

> A two-digit year that is less than or equal to the last two digits of the cutoff year is in the same century as the cutoff year. A two-digit year greater than the last two digits of the cutoff year is in the century that comes before the cutoff year. For example, if the two-digit year cutoff is the default 2049, the two-digit year 49 is interpreted as 2049 and the two-digit year 50 is interpreted as 1950.

> Un año de dos dígitos que sea menor o igual a los dos últimos dígitos del año de corte está en el mismo siglo que el año de corte. Un año de dos dígitos mayor que los dos últimos dígitos del año de corte corresponde al siglo anterior al año de corte. Por ejemplo, si el año de corte de dos dígitos es el 2049 predeterminado, el año 49 de dos dígitos se interpreta como 2049 y el año 50 de dos dígitos se interpreta como 1950.

Comment: Si funciono,Gracias

Comment: De nada @JoseLuisDeLaCruzMorales!